# JButton not being painted in my JFrame. JFrame is in while loop

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton

I am trying to create some sort of wack a mole game and i have a JFrame set in  while loop so it will create a JFrame in a new spot every second but the problem is my JButton will not load in during this process. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
public class WACKAMOLE {
private static JFrame frame;
private static JFrame frame1;
private static JButton button1;
private static int a;
private static int b;
private static int x = 0;
private static int score=0;

    public static void main(String args[]){
    Menu n=new Menu();
    n.Start();

}

static class Menu{

       public void Start(){
    frame=new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(150, 150);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    JPanel panel=new JPanel();
    JLabel label=new JLabel("Main Menu");
    JLabel label1=new JLabel("WACK A MOLE DELUXE");
    JButton button=new JButton("Start");
    JButton button1=new JButton("Highscores");
    panel.add(label1);
    panel.add(label);
    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(button1);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    button.addActionListener(new game());
    }
}

static class game implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        frame.dispose();
        Random generator=new Random();
        Random generator1=new Random();
        while(x<=30){
        a=generator.nextInt(1000);
        b=generator1.nextInt(1000);
        frame1=new JFrame("HEHE");
        frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame1.setSize(100,100);
        frame1.setLocation(a,b);
        frame1.setResizable(false);
        button1=new JButton("WACK ME!");
        button1.addActionListener(new clicked());
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame1.add(button1);
        frame1.setVisible(true);

        try{Thread.sleep(900);}
        catch(Exception e1){System.out.println("ERROR");}

        frame1.dispose();
        x++;
        }

    }

    static class clicked implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            frame1.dispose();
            x++;
            score++;

        }
    }

}

 }
```

Comment: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them

Answer (score 3):

If you make the event dispatch thread sleep, then all the GUI events and paintings are blocked. You need to use a background thread to sleep, and then trigger the dispose of the frame in the EDT from the background thread.

Read the [tutorial about concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/).